# string not being changed by reference

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, string, reference

I create 2 variables with names ***a*** and ***b*** then I initialize variable ***a*** with value ***"start"*** and later I assign variable ***a*** to variable ***b*** and finally
I change value of variable ***a*** to ***end*** but variable ***b*** don't change,
while ***a*** and ***b*** are reference types!

```
string a = "start"; // Declare and initialize a variable
string b = a; // Copy the variable's value to a new variable
a = "end"; // Modify the value of the original variable
//variable b don't change!!
```

Why is this not working as expected?

Answer (score 18):

You're misunderstanding what "reference type" means.

Think about it this way.  Imagine two houses, one at 123 Sesame Street and one at 1600 Pennyslvania Avenue.  Those are *objects of reference type*.

Now imagine that you have two pieces of paper. One says "123 Sesame Street". One says "1600 Pennsylvania Avenue".  Those are not houses; you can't move in to those pieces of paper. Those are *references* to houses.

Now imagine that you have two drawers labelled "a" and "b". Those are *variables of reference type*.

You put the "123 Sesame Street" paper into drawer "a". You do not put *the house* into the drawer. You put the *reference* to the house into the drawer.  A variable of reference type *stores a reference to an object*. That's why it is called a variable of *reference type*.

Then you make a photocopy of the paper in drawer "a" and put it in drawer "b".  "b" now contains *a copy of the reference*.  Drawers "a" and "b" now *refer to the same house*. If you paint that house red, the house referred to by the papers in both drawers is red, because there is only one house referred to by both papers. There are two references to the same house, and two variables that contain one reference each.

Then you take the paper out of drawer "a" and destroy it. You replace it with the paper that says "1600 Pennsylvania Avenue".

Doing that did not change anything about drawer "b"!  When you said "b = a", that means "make a photocopy of the reference that is in drawer a and put it in drawer b". It does *not* mean "drawers a and b are now two different names for the same drawer".

Does that make sense?

Comment: It does make sense, of course, the tricky part being the difference between `System.String` and the other reference types IMHO: reference types are usually compared by *paper in the drawer*, but strings behave as value types in this respect and actually check if both houses are painted red.

Comment: @gdoron: What does immutability have to do with it?  Suppose we replaced the user's question with "var a = new [] { 1, 2, 3}; var b = a; a = new[] { 4, 5, 6 };" and hey, b did not change even though a and b are both of reference type. For that matter, what does comparing by value have to do with anything?  The question is about the nature of copying by reference, not about immutability or comparisons.

Answer (score 6):

That's not how strings work in C#, they're not pointers. More to the point, strings are immutable so you can't change their value anyway, just assign a new one. So whatever you're trying to do you'll need to take that into account.

The fact that the comparison operator succeeds is because you're doing a literal comparison between the characters contained in each string, not because they're "equal" in the memory storage sense.

Comment: The comparison works because C# overrides that operator http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664728(v=vs.71).aspx, but you actually kind of said that.

Comment: @Ron Warholic Thank you for downvoting my answer. You might want to check the initial revision of the question to see why comparison was even mentioned. Might want to do that often, when you see comments that don't necessarily match what you see in the question.

Comment: @kprobst: What's happening here has NOTHING to do with immutability. Beyond that, you didn't really address the issue.

Comment: Even if they were pointers (they pretty much are but whatever), so what? `b` does not become an alias of `a` no matter how you look at it, `b` just "accidentally" happens to hold the same value as `a` (which can be a reference to a string)

Comment: @Jason I. Understand. That. I mentioned it because the OP seemed completely confused as to how this language works.

Answer (score 1):

If you do need to have strings changed by reference (by a function), you can put `ref` on the left of the argument's type. Otherwise, you could make a `MutableString` class, but I personally haven't had any need for a mutable string.

You could also try a `StringBuilder`, but that's not really a string.